# Threadpool thread never terminates

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I create some threads to do some work using threadpool. Every thread increments *finishedThreads* variable, so the main thread knows when all the threadpool threads terminate:

```
// in the main thread
while (finishedThreads < threadsNumber) {
    // wait
}
// threads terminated, we can continue

// last line of the threadpool thread
++finishedThreads;
```

Everything works fine until I create a big amount of threads - over 50. Then the last thread never terminates, so the *finishedThreads* is still equal *threadsNumber-1* and the main thread never continues. I tried to find out why this happens, using debugging, stopping Visual etc. but nothing helped. The thread is not being terminated, although as Visual shows, it does not execute any code. Have you got any ideas on what goes wrong? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]: That's how I create new threads:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(myThreadFunc), someData);
```

Comment: Why don't you show the actual code itself rather than an irrelevant boilerplate snippet?

Comment: Unsynchronized access to finishedThreads from different threads.

Comment: @AlexF How would you fix that?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog the actual code is quite long.

Comment: It is just buggy, threads that both read and write a shared variable must use the `lock` keyword.  A standard way that ++finishedThreads will fail is two threads executing it at the exact same time.  They'll both read, say, 0 and increment it to 1, end result is 1 instead of 2.  The while() loop will fail as well in 32-bit code in the Release build.  Multiple ways to do this correctly, consider the CountdownEvent class as a direct substitute.  But do look at Task, you'll like its WaitAll() method.

Comment: Actually instead of lock you can add/remove counters and read them using interlocked. Faster.

Comment: 1. `lock` 2. `Interlocked` Class. 3. `WaitAll` - the best solution for your case, as mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: @gogolon - The length of the code is irrelevant if it is necessary to replicate the situation. Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Or just use `Parallel.For`/`ForEach`.

Comment: I've used Task.WaitAll() and it works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care? Is it affecting the execution of your program? I've been dispatching work to the thread pool for >15 years, and I've been happy to view it mostly as a black box (unless my code was misbehaving).

Comment: Yes, it is. The next part of code has to execute after the first one, since they are using same objects which they change and it would completely mess the calculations if the program didn't wait until the first part is completed